# Accessing Firebase from Polymer Element

Tags: firebase, polymer

I am working on an app that uses Polymer and Firebase. I am trying to figure out how to access my Firebase document from my custom element. Currently, I have a view defined like this:

```
<body>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="dialog">
    <firebase-document location="https://my-app.firebaseio.com/" data="{{ orders }}"></firebase-document>

    <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
      <section data-route="home">
        <h3>Hello</h3>
      </section>

      <section data-route="orders">
        <h3>Orders</h3>
        <user-orders orders="{{ orders }}"></user-orders>
      </section>
    </iron-pages>      
  </template>  
</body>
```

The user-orders element is defined like this:

```
<dom-module id="user-orders">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ orders ]]" as="order">
      <div>[[ order.date ]]</div>
      <div>[[ order.status ]]</div>
      <div>[[ order.description ]]</div>
    </template>

    <button on-click="test">Test</button>
    <button>Add New Order</button>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "user-orders",
      properties: {
        orders: {
          type: Array,
          notify: true,
          value: function() {
            return [];
          }
        }
      },

      test: function() {
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.orders));
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The view associated with my route appears correctly. However, when I click my "Test" button, an `alert` window appears that says `null`. Its like either a) I've setup my firebase connection improperly, which I'm not sure how to actually confirm or b) My data binding is setup improperly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you working with a brand new Firebase app or an existing Firebase app? A brand new Firebase app without any data will return `null`.